# iOS Navigation Controller null after dismissing modal

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationcontroller

I have a photo selection flow that that goes as such:

**VC1 push to VC2, present modal, dismiss modal, push VC3.**

Upon dismissing the modal view however, `self.navigationController` is **`null`**

Modal View:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                                FBGalleryVC *vc = [[FBGalleryVC alloc] init];
                                [vc showVC3];
                            }];
```

Triggers VC2:

```
- (void)showVC3 {
    NSLog(@"NavController=%@",self.navigationController);
    VC3 *vc3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC3"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3 animated:YES];
}
```

It's unclear to me why the navigationController is getting 'unset' or returning as null.

Comment: How and where is `showVC3` called?

Comment: Sorry, edited to show, it's called after the completion of dismissViewControllerAnimated.

Comment: How did you push the modal viewcontroller?

Comment: This is how I present the modal vc.

`ImageCropperVC *vc = [[ImageCropperVC alloc] initWithImage:cell.imageview.image];
            [self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: how did you push the VC2?

Comment: This is how we push the VC2 onto VC1, it uses a Storyboard segue so maybe that's something?

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FBGalleryVC" sender:nil];
}`

Comment: it is `nil` because the `vc` is a brand new instance of the `FBGalleryVC`, you are creating it in the completion block and it has never gone into any navigation stack, therefore its `navigationController` property is `nil`.

Comment: Many thanks to @holex - Very silly mistake on my part.